# In Excel, how do I extract or copy last letters of a string?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, extract

For example: I have the following values in ONE Column

AD ANDORRA
AE UNITED ARAB EMIRATES
AF AFGHANISTAN

I want to ignore the first two digits and copy everything else on the right to a different column. Is there a formula I can use?

Comment: MID() is the formula to use.

Comment: Skip the formulas and use Data ► Text to Column ► Fixed Width ► Finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its always Just 2 characters and a space at the start then you can use

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-3)
```

If it could be more than two letters before the space then you can use RIGHT,LEN and FIND to do this

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-(FIND(" ",A1,1)))
```

FIND will find the position of the space.
LEN will give the length of the total string

RIGHT will take the right side of the string a number of chars, which will be the Length of the total string minus the position of the space.

Answer (score 0):

If your country abbreviation and country are in A1, then you could retrieve the 4th character onward (that is, skipping the two letters and the space) by using:

```
=MID(A1,4,LEN(A1))
```